# failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.7

Tags: java, maven

I'm getting this error all of a sudden in maven and i'm not sure why:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) on project

org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.7:resources (default-resources) on project
```

I searched in intellij for 2.7 as well as maven-resources-plugin and we aren't using those.  Why is maven suddenly complaining about this when I don't even use that plugin?

Comment: The resources plugin is part of the default lifecycle (process-resources phase). Have you tried to run it with mvn -X to get a stack trace?

Comment: Maven works with plugins. Everything in maven is executed via plugins. That is the default plugin for resources matters. Probably you have something wrong with your resources folder or resources configuration in pom.xml

Comment: Could you please post al the ERROR level logs that the execution shows?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with the maven-filtering dependency.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.7</version>
<dependencies>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-filtering</artifactId>
   <version>1.3</version>
 </dependency>
</dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: In such cases I would suggest to upgrade to the most recent version of  [maven-resources-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) ...

Answer (score 0):

I had .der files in my src/main/resources which now when removed it builds successfully.

Comment: What are `.der` files?

Comment: @khmarbaise basically i had encrypted keys that i was using for testing.

Comment: If you have activated filtering you should turn that off for those files and you should use most recent version of maven-resources-plugin.